# Issues with Bootstrap Label and Input Field Alignment

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following form in my Angular app Using Bootstrap 4. I want my form label and input text box to be on the same line but its not working. The label and the input text box appears on separate lines. I have searched but couldn't find any better answer ::

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-12">
  <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="parentCategoryForm" autoComplete="off">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="parent">Category name</label>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" formControlName="parentName" name="parentName" class="form-control" id="parentName" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
      <button type="button" (click)="cancel()" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mr-4">Cancel</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

I am following the tutorials from this site [Creating Horizontal Form Layout](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

please add class row on form-group

```
<div class="form-group row"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **input-group** class. Follow [This](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_forms_input_group.asp)

Comment: Add labels and inputs to the input-group class in the new div.